# busqueda caracter python

Tags: python

Se quiere buscar el carácter "a" dentro de una cadena
y escribir, en una cadena nueva,
el resto de caracteres, desde la primera "a" hasta el final
(por ejemplo, en la cadena "zapato" se escribiría "apato").
Si "a" no está en la cadena, crear una cadena vacía.

```
cadena = str(input("Escribe una cadena: "))
busqueda = str("a")

if cadena.find(busqueda) >= 0:
    print("El caracter " + busqueda + " se encuentra dentro de la cadena.")
    subcadena = cadena[a:]
    print("La nueva cadena es: ", subcadena)
else:
    print("El caracter " + busqueda + " no se encuentra dentro de la cadena.")
```

Me aparece este error:

> slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de hacer una substring y le estás pasando una "a" como delimitador inicial

```
cadena[a:]
```

Pero `a` no existe, te dejo algo funcionando

```
cadena   = str(input("Escribe una cadena: "))
busqueda = str("a")
found    = cadena.find(busqueda)
if found >= 0:
    print("El caracter " + busqueda + " se encuentra dentro de la cadena.")
    subcadena = cadena[found:]
    print("La nueva cadena es: ", subcadena)
else:
    print("El caracter " + busqueda + " no se encuentra dentro de la cadena.")
```

Comment: Alberto, la línea 2 debería haber sido **busqueda = "a"**.